# Парсинг XML значений double

Tags: c#, xml, синтаксический-анализ

Всем добрый день.

Есть XML файл в котором нужно спарсить значения `double`. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно спарсить через `double.Parse()`. Вот собственно и сам кусочек:

```
<Width>245.50</Width>      
  <IntersectionPlane>
    <X>0.000</X>
    <Y>0.000</Y>
    <Z>1.000</Z>
  </IntersectionPlane>
  <IntersectionPlane>
    <X>0.000</X>
    <Y>-300.000</Y>
    <Z>-0.000</Z>
  </IntersectionPlane>
  <IntersectionPlane>
    <X>-0.000</X>
    <Y>-0.000</Y>
    <Z>300.000</Z>
  </IntersectionPlane>
```

Сериализацию файла делала через `XmlSerializer` соответсвенно чтение через `Deserialize`. Пробовала парсить значения через `string.Split()`, не получается. Подскажите как можно было бы это реализовать. Хотелось бы что бы было что то наподобие этого:

```
round.Width = double.Parse(tokens[0]);
plane.PlaneIntersection = new Point3D(ParseDouble(tokens[0]), ParseDouble(tokens[1]), ParseDouble(tokens[2]));
```

Код метода `ParseDouble(string digit):`

```
private double ParseDouble(string digit)
    {
        double res;

        double.TryParse(digit, style, culture, out res);

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Не понимаю зачем вам парсить xml, если вы уже сделали Deserialize (т.е. у вас уже должен быть какой-то массив объектов типа IntersectionPlane где хранятся x,y и z). Ну а так посмотрите в сторону 
http://habrahabr.ru/post/24673/ и
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, проблема в том, какой десятичный разделитель установлен в настройках ОС.